# Powershell: How can I stop errors from being displayed in a script?

Tags: powershell, error-handling

When my PowerShell script tries, for example, to create a SQL Server object for a server that doesn't exist ("bla" in my case), PowerShell displays lots of PowerShell errors in red.

Since my script checks the value of `$?` after such calls, and displays and logs errors, I'd rather not have the several lines of PowerShell errors displayed as well.

How can I deactivate those being displayed for my script?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

You have a couple of options.  The easiest involve using the `ErrorAction` settings.

`-Erroraction` is a universal parameter for all cmdlets.  If there are special commands you want to ignore you can use `-erroraction 'silentlycontinue'` which will basically ignore all error messages generated by that command. You can also use the `Ignore` value (in PowerShell 3+):

> Unlike SilentlyContinue, Ignore does not add the error message to the $Error automatic variable.

If you want to ignore all errors in a script, you can use the system variable `$ErrorActionPreference` and do the same thing: `$ErrorActionPreference= 'silentlycontinue'`

See [about_CommonParameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847884.aspx) for more info about -ErrorAction.
See [about_preference_variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables) for more info about $ErrorActionPreference.

Comment: do you need single quote in  -erroraction 'silentlycontinue'? Intellisese is showing options and not adding single quote.

Comment: If the format above doesn't work for you, reference the link provided above.  I had to format as `-ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue` in PS 5.1.  I was calling my cmdlet from batch so I don't know if that makes a difference.  But good info when you know an acceptable  error may be thrown.

Comment: --rm .\Windows.old\ -Force -Recurse -Verbose -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue </code>

Answer (score 29):

You can also append `2>$null` to your command.

Example:

```
$rec = Resolve-DnsName $fqdn -Server $dns 2>$null
```

Comment: Though it may not be the "proper" way, this is perfect for handling broken CmdLets that output errors no matter the error preference switch or variable. Just had to do this for Get-CsOnlineVoiceUser version 3.1.1, which must use Get-CsUser under the hood without properly handling its errors.

Comment: This one works when executing non-powershell commands in powershell. For example, only this solution works when calling "taskkil"

Comment: So how do I do this per selective line? I have this simple script that restores my quick access pins but sometimes I move folders and the commands for those specific entries just point to a null object, hence the errors... which is fine. I can't seem to make it work this way... only with try catch which is a bit more to write than 2>$null, pardon my laziness

Answer (score 24):

Windows PowerShell provides two mechanisms for reporting errors: one mechanism for *terminating errors* and another mechanism for *non-terminating errors*.

Internal CmdLets code can call a `ThrowTerminatingError` method when an error occurs that does not or should not allow the cmdlet to continue to process its input objects. The script writter can them use exception to catch these error.

EX :

```
try
{
  Your database code
}
catch
{
  Error reporting/logging
}
```

Internal CmdLets code can call a `WriteError` method to report non-terminating errors when the cmdlet can continue processing the input objects. The script writer can then use -ErrorAction option to hide the messages, or use the `$ErrorActionPreference` to setup the entire script behaviour.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem when trying to resolve host names using `[system.net.dns]`. If the IP wasn't resolved .Net threw a terminating error.
To prevent the terminating error and still retain control of the output, I created a function using `TRAP`.

E.G.

```
Function Get-IP 
{PARAM   ([string]$HostName="")
PROCESS {TRAP 
             {"" ;continue} 
             [system.net.dns]::gethostaddresses($HostName)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to your script and you'll be good to go.

Comment: How do you add -ErrorAction SiltentlyContinue to the script? Could you post an example?

Comment: Using this flag the script can continue without error but error message may still be printed for some commands. For this command it continues and does not print an error message: "$result = Test-Path $path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue", but for this "$AppPool = Get-WebAppPoolState $sitename -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue" it continues and prints an error message

Comment: Letting your program continue when the previous action failed is almost always a bad idea. There are very few times when your program can do anything useful after an operation fails.

Answer (score 6):

You're way off track here. Silencing errors is almost never a good idea, and manually checking `$?` explicitly after *every single command* is enormously cumbersome and easy to forget to do (error prone). Don't set yourself up to easily make a mistake. If you're getting lots and lots of red, that means your script kept going when it should have stopped instead. It can no longer do useful work if most of its commands are failing. Continuing a program when it and the system are in an unknown state will have unknown consequences; you could easily leave the system in a corrupt state.

The correct solution is to stop the algorithm on the first error. This principle is called "fail fast," and PowerShell has a built in mechanism to enable that behavior. It is a setting called the [error preference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables#erroractionpreference), and setting it to the highest level will make your script (and the child scopes if they don't override it) behave this way:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
```

This will produce a nice, big error message for your consumption and prevent the following commands from executing the first time something goes wrong, without having to check `$?` every single time you run a command. This makes the code vastly simpler and more reliable. I put it at the top of every single script I ever write, and you almost certainly should as well.

In the rare cases where you can be absolutely certain that allowing the script to continue makes sense, you can use one of two mechanisms:

- [`catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally): This is the better and more flexible mechanism. You can wrap a `try`/`catch` block around multiple commands, allowing the first error to stop the sequence and jump into the handler where you can log it and then otherwise recover from it or rethrow it to bubble the error up even further. You can also limit the `catch` to specific errors, meaning that it will only be invoked in specific situations you anticipated rather than any error. (For example, failing to create a file because it already exists warrants a different response than a security failure.)
- The common [`-ErrorAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters) parameter: This parameter changes the error handling for one single function call, but you cannot limit it to specific types of errors. You should only use this if you can be certain that the script can continue on *any* error, not just the ones you can anticipate.

In your case, you probably want one big `try`/`catch` block around your entire program. Then your process will stop on the first error and the `catch` block can log it before exiting. This will remove a lot of duplicate code from your program in addition to cleaning up your log file and terminal output and making your program less likely to cause problems.

Do note that this doesn't handle the case when external executables fail (exit code nonzero, conventionally), so you do still need to check `$LASTEXITCODE` if you invoke any. Despite this limitation, the setting still saves a lot of code and effort.

#### Additional reliability

You might also want to consider using [strict mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode):

```
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
```

This prevents PowerShell from silently proceeding when you use a non-existent variable and in other weird situations. (See the `-Version` parameter for details about what it restricts.)

Combining these two settings makes PowerShell much more of fail-fast language, which makes programming in it vastly easier.

Comment: You claim this makes it more reliable but in the case of any automation it does the opposite. Sometimes there are scripts that should run regardless of whether there's an error with a previous cmdlet and it's much easier to distribute a single powershell script than one per required action. With your solution, if a file that needs to be deleted on startup isn't there (because windows) then none of the later cmdlets in that script will be run despite the system being in the required state. Congrats, you now have a broken script running remotely with errors that aren't being pushed to a log file

Comment: @TheHitchenator The way you handle a file already existing is you write the code to keep going if it exists. You don't need to silence errors for that; you just check if it exists first or use `-Force` or something else depending on the exact behavior you need. If you just silence errors, your script will keep going when creating the files fails due to security policy, and it will not work correctly and may even corrupt the system further. Letting a broken script continue is far more dangerous than finding out you forgot to handle a particular system state.

Comment: you're literally providing an answer to a question of "how do I disable this error output? I've got my own error checking built into the script" by saying "don't do that, just let the errors block the script instead." Clearly if they've got error checking built into it then they're going to handle these issues. You're not being helpful, just needlessly contrarian because you are failing to envision an environment in which things don't work the way you're used to. Please, when providing answers, actually answer the question rather than just telling someone not to do something.

Comment: @TheHitchenator If the following commands are all failing anyway (as evidenced by the large number of errors the OP is getting), there is no reason to execute them. It has nothing to do with my imagination and everything to do with the evidence given to us. The approach is flawed and creates work and increases the chance of creating problems. No one is served well by being left to continue down a bad path without an alternative. SO has always explicitly encouraged providing better alternative approaches.

Comment: @TheHitchenator Also, if you had actually read my answer (both before and after the recent edits), it *does* explain how to manage errors.

Answer (score 3):

**To extend on Mikkel's answer**.

If you still want to capture the error, you can use "-ErrorAction stop" combined with a try - catch.

*"-ErrorAction silentlycontinue" will ignore the error.*

**For instance:**

```
try
{
    New-Item -Path "/somepath" -Name "somename" -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
}
catch
{
    echo "You must run this command in an elevated mode."
}
```

NOTE: There is no "silentlyStop" action, and I believe Mickel's answer refers to the "stop" action. It is likely a typo.
The idea of using a try-catch combined with the "stop" action is to be able to not just dismiss eventual errors but to show something in case of errors.

Answer (score 2):

In some cases you can pipe after the command a Out-Null

```
command | Out-Null
```

Comment: This never silences _error_ output, only _success_ output.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the powershell errormessage for a cmdlet suppressed, but still want to catch the error, use "-erroraction 'silentlyStop'"

Comment: There is no such action. Altough there is a Stop action.

Comment: But it allow to suppress red error message and still use catch command/section when using `New-Item -ItemType directory` (PowerShell v2.0)

Comment: @MilanKerslager could you kindly show a code sample - since I, and everyone else, believe that there is no such ActionPreference as 'SilentlyStop'

Comment: I'm reasonably confident that Mikkel meant SilentlyContinue rather than silentlyStop, because that makes a lot more sense in the content of what you want it to be doing.