# How to avoid an UnathorizedAccessException when using Get-ChildItem?

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am using PowerShell 5.0 and working on a script to find and list all the versions of log4net.dll under the current directory recursively.

```
Get-ChildItem log4net.dll -Recurse | % versioninfo | Export-Csv "C:\MyJunk\log4net.csv"
```

The above statement begins returning version information as expected but execution stops at the first folder I lack permission to access:

```
Get-ChildItem : The specified network name is no longer available.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem log4net.dll -Recurse | % versioninfo | Export-Csv "C:\M ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (J:\ArcPlan_OracleWallet\Production:String) [Get-ChildItem], IOException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : Access is denied
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem log4net.dll -Recurse | % versioninfo | Export-Csv "C:\M ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

I am running Windows PowerShell ISE as Adminstrator. ExecutionPolicy is RemoteSigned and $ErrorActionPreference is Continue.

Ideally I would like the script to interrogate each folder's ACL and bypass all folders (and their contents) I lack permission to access.  However another solution would one in which hard-coded folders are bypassed.  Being a novice in PowerShell I focused on the later.

I have tried bypassing the first problem folder (by name) to see if I could get that working, but encounter the same exception and processing stops.

```
Get-ChildItem log4net.dll -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.FullName -notmatch '\\ArcPlan_OracleWallet\\?'} | export-csv 'C:\MyJunk\log4net.csv'
```

Thanks.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`?

Comment: @Ansgar.  Thanks for the replay.  I still get the Access is denied exception.

Comment: `The specified network name is no longer available` is this error message incorrect or do you really have a network issue? Maybe this is why the script execution stops?

Comment: @sodawillow I don't believe so.  Using the command prompt I can open to the "J:\ArcPlan_OracleWallet" folder and view its contents.  When I attempt `cd production` I get the Access is denied. error.

Comment: Have you tried `Get-ChildItem -Force`?

Comment: I believe the issue was that the `Get-ChildItem log4net.dll -Recurse` would fail before the `Where-Object` could filter out the unwanted directories.  My solution is fugly.  It's too long to post here so I'll add it as an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue was that the `Get-ChildItem log4net.dll -Recurse` would fail before the `Where-Object` could filter out the unwanted directories.

I want to avoid hard-coding directories, but here is my (klunky) solution so far.

```
## Version information will be retrieved for $fileName
$fileName = 'log4net.dll'

$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'

## Get directies - excluding those you lack permission to access
$directories = Get-ChildItem -Directory | 
    Where-Object {$_.FullName -inotmatch 'directory-1' -and 
                $_.FullName -inotmatch 'directory-2' -and
                $_.FullName -inotmatch 'directory-3'                    
} 

## Array to hold version information
$allFilesVersionInfo = @()

foreach ($directory in $directories) {

    ## Get all files recursively
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $directory.FullName $fileName -Recurse 

    foreach ($file in $files) {

        ## Get version information and add to array
        $fileVersionInfo = $file | % versioninfo 
        $allFilesVersionInfo += $fileVersionInfo
    }
}

# Write version information in arra to file
$exportFullPath = "C:\MyJunk\$($fileName)-version.csv"
$allFilesVersionInfo |  Export-Csv -Path $($exportFullPath)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ignore the errors, use `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`.

There are other useful values to this parameter, as you can discover [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/11/02/erroraction-and-errorvariable/) and [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/09/handling-errors-the-powershell-way/).

[Here is a nice question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388650/powershell-how-can-i-stop-errors-from-being-displayed-in-a-script/8388822#8388822) quite on-topic.

You can also fetch help about this with `Get-Help about_CommonParameters`.

(Hi and welcome, if you dig this answer, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ^^).

Comment: I use `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` fairly often, and have found the shorter alias `-ea 4` to be easier and faster to type. `-ea` is an alias for `-ErrorAction` and `4` because `SilentlyContinue` is the fourth item in the [ActionPreference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.actionpreference(v=vs.85).aspx) enum.

Comment: I think proper short version should be -ea 0

`PS H:\> 0..5 | % {write-Host $_
 ([System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]$_)}`

`0 SilentlyContinue`

`1 Stop`

`2 Continue`

`3 Inquire`

`4 Ignore`

`5 Suspend`

Comment: I've used `if (Test-Connection $host -Quiet -Count 2 -EA 0) { #host is online, go on }` many times before understanding the `-EA 0` bit : )

Comment: @sodawillow.  Thanks for the info.  SilentlyContinue hides the errors, but the command still stops.

Comment: @SteveBrueckman see my comment on your Q, let's go debug some more then :).

Comment: Just for the record, I also can see that the "-ErrorAction Continue -force" (Continue or SilentlyContinue) stops when a System.UnauthorizedAccessException is thrown. It can continue when a " FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError" is encountered.