# How to avoid unnecessary output from [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("$server_name")

Tags: powershell

```
$inventory = Import-Csv "E:\MonitoringScripts\HealthCheck\PatStat_Pshell\inventory.csv"
foreach ($line in $inventory) {
    $server_name = $($line.servername)
    $port_number = $($line.port)
    $resolved_true = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("$server_name") 
    #Write-Host $resolved_true
    if ($resolved_true) {
        #Write-Host $server_name
        Write-Host 'the host is resolving'
    } else {
        Write-Host 'Not found in DNS'
    }
}
```

In the above code, how do I avoid the below content to appear in the command promt when there is a host in the inventory file which is not resolving the dns?

```
Exception calling "GetHostAddresses" with "1" argument(s): "No such host is
known"
At E:\MonitoringScripts\HealthCheck\PatStat_Pshell\patrol.ps1:9 char:2
+     $resolved_true = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("$server_name")
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SocketException

Not found in DNS
the host is resolving
```

I just want to see:

```
Not found in DNS
```

or

```
the host is resolving
```

Comment: First you should remove the quotes around the variable `$server_name`. How to you run this code?

Comment: PS E:\MonitoringScripts\HealthCheck\PatStat_Pshell> .\patrol.ps1
Exception calling "GetHostAddresses" with "1" argument(s): "No such host is
known"
At E:\MonitoringScripts\HealthCheck\PatStat_Pshell\patrol.ps1:9 char:2
+     $resolved_true = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("$server_name") |
foreach { ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SocketException

Not found in DNS
the host is resolving

Comment: Its running fine event with out removing the double quots. but as suggested i will go ahead and remove it.

Comment: take a look at the 3rd answer here ... Powershell: How can I stop errors from being displayed in a script? - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388650/powershell-how-can-i-stop-errors-from-being-displayed-in-a-script

Comment: You might use `if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $server_name) {`

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I could not get it.. quite new to scripting.
my main concern is to not to get the error when the host does not resolve.
could you please modify the above lines ?

Comment: @lit I am not just checking for icmp connection i want to check if the host resolves to an IP address. so i cannot use `Test-Connection`

Comment: @kaushikkm - simply add the function to the top of your script and then replace calls to that static method with the function call. [*grin*]

Comment: @kaushikkm - Are you saying that you might find it in DNS even if the host is not up and available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [About Try Catch Finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-6):

> Use Try, Catch, and Finally blocks to respond to or handle terminating
>   errors in scripts.

You can apply it as follows:

```
try {
    $resolved_true = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($server_name)
} catch {
    $resolved_true = $null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Catch the exception:

```
try {
    [Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($server_name)
    Write-Host 'the host is resolving'
} catch {
    Write-Host 'Not found in DNS'
}
```

Comment: Exception calling "GetHostAddresses" with "1" argument(s): "No such host is
known"
At E:\MonitoringScripts\HealthCheck\PatStat_Pshell\patrol.ps1:9 char:2
+     $resolved_true = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($server_name)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordE
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SocketException

Comment: yes @Ansgar Wiechers,
i am trying to post the code which i tried.. unable to post it with proper indentation

Comment: Just click on the "edit" link right below your question and add your modified code. BTW, what output does `$PSVersionTable` give you? Include that output as well.

Comment: here it was executing the command and giving the output of `[Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($server_name)` which is not required

Comment: PSVersion                      3.0                                                                              
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                              
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                          
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.36470                                                                  
BuildVersion                   6.2.9200.22198

Comment: @kaushikkm Then you did not run the command in a `try..catch` statement. Plain and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Test-Connection to see if the host exists first. Of course, the host existing is not exactly the same thing as finding it in DNS.

```
$inventory = import-csv “E:\MonitoringScripts\HealthCheck\PatStat_Pshell\inventory.csv”
ForEach ($line in $inventory)
{
    $server_name = $($line.servername)
    $port_number = $($line.port)
    $resolved_true = $null
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $server_name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        $resolved_true = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("$server_name")
    }
    #Write-host $resolved_true
    if($resolved_true) {
        #write-host $server_name
        Write-Host 'the host is resolving'
    } else {
        Write-Host 'Not found in DNS'
    }
}
```

Comment: Test-connection started to throw error, as it was not able to find the host.
i just do not want the error to be thrown, let it go to the else condition

Comment: PS E:\MonitoringScripts\HealthCheck\PatStat_Pshell> .\patrol2.ps1
Test-Connection : Testing connection to computer 'vlhebsadv06abc' failed: The
requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found
At E:\MonitoringScripts\HealthCheck\PatStat_Pshell\patrol2.ps1:7 char:9
+     if (Test-Connection $server_name) {
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (vlhebsadv06abc:String) [Te
   st-Connection], PingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestConnectionException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Com
   mands.TestConnectionCommnd

Comment: how to use -ErrorAction ?

Comment: wow this is what i was looking for. Thank you.
not sure why.. but it is taking very long time to execute. any idea ? or how to improve ? i am just running this for two hosts.. and it took 4-5 seconds
i would want to run this on more than 2K hosts

Comment: @kaushikkm - Actually, the try/catch exception handling approach would be more direct. I am surprised it did not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$inventory = import-csv “E:\MonitoringScripts\HealthCheck\PatStat_Pshell\inventory.csv”
ForEach ($line in $inventory)
{
    $server_name = $($line.servername)
    $port_number = $($line.port)
    $resolved_true = $null
    try {
    $resolved_true = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($server_name) 
    } catch {
    $resolved_true = $null
    }
    #Write-host $resolved_true
    if($resolved_true) {
        #write-host $server_name
        Write-Host 'the host is resolving'
    } else {
        Write-Host 'Not found in DNS'
    }
}
```

This worked for me, Thank you so much all for the help.
I will have to mark @JosefZ Answer, But really thank you all.